# Page update when item is created

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have a page where people can create notes, they are added to the page through ajax. I need to implement SignalR functionality to update the page whenever new item is created. I couldnt grasp onto the idea how to do that, any help would be gladly appriciated!

Comment: What is it exactly that you're struggling with? The documentation is pretty clear. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

> I have a page where people can create notes, they are added to the page through ajax. I need to implement SignalR functionality to update the page whenever new item is created.

Based on your requirement, I create the following sample, which work well on my side, please refer to it.

**Hub Class**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("NoteUpdateNotification", user, message);
    }
}
```

**Index Page**

```
@model IEnumerable<NotesRTMSignalR.Models.NoteInfo>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts {
    <style>
        .newnote{
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>


    <script>
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

        connection.on("NoteUpdateNotification", function (user, message) {
            console.log(user + " updated/added a note, the details is '" + message + "'");

            $("tr.newnote").removeClass("newnote");
            var note = JSON.parse(message);
            var tr = "<tr class='newnote'><td>" + note.Id +
                "</td><td>" + note.Title +
                "</td><td>" + note.Description +
                "</td><td>" + note.Author +
                "</td><td><a href=''>Edit</a> |<a href=''>Details</a> |<a href=''>Delete</a></td></tr>"

            $("tbody").append(tr);
        });

        connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("connection started");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Create Page**

```
<script>
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

    //connection.on("NoteUpdateNotification", function (user, message) {
    //    alert(user + " updated/added a note, the details is '" + message + "'");
    //});

    connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log("connection started");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    $(function () {
        $("input[type='submit']").click(function (e) {

            var note = { "Id": $("input[id='Id']").val(), "Title": $("input[id='Title']").val(), "Description": $("input[id='Description']").val(), "Author": $("input[id='Author']").val() };
            //alert(JSON.stringify(note));
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Note/CreateNote",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(note),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (res) {
                    connection.invoke("SendMessage", $("input[id='Author']").val(), JSON.stringify(note)).catch(function (err) {
                        return console.error(err.toString());
                    });

                    alert("Note Update/Add Notification Is Sent To Others");
                },
                failure: function (err) {

                }
            })
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    })
</script>
```

**Test Result**

[image]

**Note**: You can get started with [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-signalr-hub) first, then setup SignalR JavaScript Client Application based on your scenario and requirement.

Comment: Hi @TihomirTodorov, any updates? Did you try the above example that I shared? If you have any questions, please post back.